# prior art and new submissions but applicants names altered

Tags: patentability

I was a co-applicant on US20070112261. Subsequently granted Patents US8207859B2 and US8207860B2 quote the the earlier application as  prior art but my name was was removed from the later successful submissions without my consent even though much of the content is very similar? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to US 8207859. Both it and the '860 refer back to a common provisional application filed in 2008. The publication 20070112261 covers similar material and has one inventor in common but does not have a common history with the others. You probably know that the '261 document is a publication of an application, not a granted patent. It does not seem to have resulted in an issued patent.

Inventorship has to do with what is claimed. Two applications can be identical except for the claims and have different lists of inventors. You are named as inventor if you made a conceptual contribution to something that is claimed.